# Count the number of terms that are not atoms in a nested list

Tags: prolog

I have these facts:

```
vehicle(car,blue,[wheel,horn,optional(radio)]).
vehicle(motorcycle,blue,[wheel,optional(navigation),horn]).
vehicle(truck,white,[wheel,horn,optional(trailer)]).
```

I want to count all optional items (all "optional") of all blue vehicles - in this case 2.
Right now I have a predicate that creates a nested list with the component lists of all blue vehicles:

```
countAllOptionalComponents:-
    findall(X,vehicle(_,blue,X),S),
    write(S).
```

[ [wheel,horn,optional(radio)], [wheel,optional(navigation),horn] ]

My idea was to pass this nested list to another predicate to count all optional components of all "sub-lists", but I'm having trouble. Something like this:

```
countAllOptionalComponents:-
    findall(X,vehicle(_,blue,X),S),
    countOptComponents(S,N).

countOptComponents([],0).
countOptComponents([X,Y],N):-
[...]
```

Maybe the approach I'm following doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution would be the following:

```
count(C) :-
    findall(X, vehicle(_, blue, X), Ls),
    countOpt(Ls, 0, C).

countOpt([], X, X) :- !.
countOpt([H|T], C, NewC) :-
    countOpt(T, C, NewC1),
    findall(Opt, member(optional(Opt), H), Opts),
    printOpts(Opts),
    length(Opts, Length),
    NewC is NewC1 + Length, !.

printOpts([]).
printOpts([H|T]) :-
    print(H),
    nl,
    printOpts(T).
```

As in your approach, first gather all lists of features (I guess?) for each vehicle and save it in a List of lists called `Ls`.

Then select in each sublist of `Ls` all Optional values (`Opt`) and add all the lengths of them.

I also added the predicate to print the results.

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain to me why the `countOpt` predicate needs three terms, namely the one in the middle (`C`)? It seems that the middle term is never used and that the first and second were sufficient. Sorry, I'm new to Prolog. By the way, if in addition to counting the optional items, I wanted to print them (example: radio, navigation), what would I have to do? I called another predicate below the `findall` predicate (inside the `countOpt` predicate), but at this point it's printing all components (not just the optional ones). Thanks again!

Comment: The third term is used to propagate the result back to the initial call. For more information when and how to use this, I would suggest to read about Prolog accumulators. I also added the predicate to print the optional values. `nl` just prints a new line.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation about the use of the third term. As for printing options, your solution is not working: numbers appear. I think it's because of the `member` predicate (inside the `findall` predicate) which only returns true/false; the Opts variable at this point has a list of numbers. Right now I'm passing the variable `H` to the `printOpts` predicate and it's printing everything (atoms and optional()). I'm having trouble printing only what's inside optional().

Comment: You are right, I missed the `Opt` in the member call, now it should work.
You can also just call `print(Opts)` after the `findall` call, but then the list is just printed as a list. I prefer printing the values one by one, but of course it's up to you.

Answer (score 2):

If you are already using `findall()` and you know that there can be more than one goal in the middle of findall by wrapping it in () then you can put another findall in there:

```
countAllOptionalComponents(OptionCount) :-
    findall(CarOptions,
        (vehicle(_, blue, CarAllItems),
         findall(O, member(optional(O), CarAllItems), CarOptions)
        ), AllOptionsNested),
    append(AllOptionsNested, AllOptions),
    write(AllOptions),
    length(AllOptions, OptionCount).
```

append/2 flattens nested lists,  `append([[horn], [radio,aircon]], [horn,radio,aircon])`.